# Kafka: Adding batches of old data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stream-processing

Using Kafka for time-based events, using windowing to group events(sessioning) in Kafka Streams.

How should we handle the arrival of a set of data from a different source, which consists of old data?

Say for example, you are doing web analytics for a client. 
You receive event data from a client in an event topic, where you receive all event types.
For some reason you did not receive order(purchases) data from a client, you only received pageview data from which you build sessions.
Some time later, you receive a batch of time-based orders, say from the last year, so you can match them with the sessions (associate which sessions are related to which order).
Output of this process is sent to "orders", "pageviews", "sessions", etc. topics.

However, if you just add them to the (end of the) topic, they will be "unordered", so even if you recalculate data, your results will not be correct.

This is somehow similar to the streaming *out-of-order events* problem, but allowing a much longer time (e.g. a year)

A possibility would be to "delete and rewrite": on a topic with compaction, delete all data from that client, and resending it again in order, and then launch a recalculation for that client.

But that's quite cumbersome. 
Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Kafka Streams can handle out-of-order data natively. If you provide enough storage capacity, you can define retention time large enough and you should be good to go. Overall, your question seems to be rather generic and hard to answer. There are too many dependencies and unknowns.